# Get position of a value in a matrix (numpy.float64)

Tags: python, numpy

im trying to find the position in minimun value of a matrix. Like in the image. In that case the min value is -35 so i need to find the position: `(2,4)`. It does not matter if i get the answer in rows or colums or starting the rows and colums at 1 or 0.

I tried to use the `np.where()` command but is not working. Data is numpy.float64 type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in the documentation for [`np.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html), and can be achieved using `np.unravel_index`:

**Example**:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random((5,5))

>>> x                                                                                                                                                                                                              
array([[0.27272346, 0.98320703, 0.60834759, 0.2069243 , 0.90370303],                                                                                                                                               
       [0.87209273, 0.52894458, 0.68152673, 0.25921476, 0.58229599],
       [0.27519671, 0.13970337, 0.57864639, 0.37383134, 0.97409805],
       [0.48481975, 0.19691474, 0.4825715 , 0.91004626, 0.34862765],
       [0.51914768, 0.43313715, 0.2819287 , 0.60615095, 0.12990098]])

>>> np.unravel_index(np.argmin(x, axis=None), x.shape)                                                                                                                                                             
(4, 4)
```

Note that an `np.where` solution is also possible:

```
>>> np.where(x == np.min(x))                                                                                                                                                                                       
(array([4]), array([4]))
```